# perl: best way to match, save and replace a regex globally

Tags: regex, perl

In a string I want to find all matches of a regex in a string, save the matches and replace the matches. Is there a *slick* way to do that?

Example:

```
my $re = qr{\wat};
my $text = "a cat a hat the bat some fat for a rat";
... (substitute $re -> 'xxx' saving matches in @matches)
# $text -> 'a xxx a xxx the xxx some xxx for a xxx'
# @matches -> qw(cat hat bat fat rat)
```

I've tried: `@matches = ($text =~ s{($re)}{xxx}g)` but it gives me a count.

Do I have to add some executable code onto the end of pattern `$re`?

Update: Here is a method which uses the code execution extended pattern `(?{ ... })`:

```
use re 'eval';  # perl complained otherwise
my $re = qr{\wat};
my $text = "a cat a hat the bat some fat for a rat";

my @x;
$text =~ s{ ($re)(?{ push(@x, $1)}) }{xxx}gx;

say "text = $text";
say Dumper(\@x); use Data::Dumper;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to the approach in your Update, but a bit easier to read:

```
$text =~ s/($re)/push @x, $1; 'xxx'/ge;
```

Or this way (probably slower):

```
push @x, $1 while $text =~ s/($re)/xxx/;
```

But, really, is there anything wrong with *unslick*?

```
my @x = $text =~ /($re)/g;
$text =~ s/($re)/xxx/g;
```

Comment: The second way will re-scan `$text` from the beginning on every iteration through the `while` loop - right? Is there a way to use `\G` here?

Comment: 2nd is not equivalent to 1st. Consider `$re = 'xx'`, for example.

Comment: +1 for first answer (clearly the best).  -1 for the second (could cause an infinite loop) and third (won't work if `$re` has a capturing group inside).  I guess it's a wash.

Comment: @Sean I follow your points, but I don't think the OP was asking for solutions that would handle arbitrary combinations of regex and input data.

Answer (score 3):

If by "slick" you mean "employs uncommonly-used language features" or "will make other programmers scratch their heads," then maybe this is the solution for you:

```
my ($temp, @matches);

push @matches, \substr($text, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]) while $text =~ /\wat/g;

$temp = $$_, $$_ = 'xxx', $_ = $temp for reverse @matches;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @x = map { $str =~ s/$_/xxx/; $_ } $str =~ /($re)/g;
```